# Integral of $2-$form along torus.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $F: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be the smooth map given via

$$(\theta,\phi) \mapsto ((2+\cos \phi)\cos\theta,(2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta,\sin\phi).$$

Let $M$ be $F(\Bbb{R}^2)$ the torus.

Let $\omega$ be the $2-$form

$$\omega=x^2 \, dy \wedge dz.$$

Compute $F^* \omega$ and use this to compute $\int_M \omega$.

**Attempt:**

As the torus is orientation preserving, we can use

$$\int_M \omega = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}F^*\omega.$$

So I computed $F^* \omega$ as follows:

\begin{align}
F^*\omega&=F^*(x^2 \, dy \wedge dz)\\
&=(2+\cos\phi)^2\cos^2\theta \, d((2+\cos\phi)\sin\theta) \wedge d(\sin\phi)\\
&=(2+\cos\phi)^2\cos^2\theta(-\sin\phi \sin \theta\, d \phi+\cos\theta(2+\cos\phi)\,d\theta) \wedge \cos\phi\, d\phi\\
&=(2+\cos\phi)^3\cos^3\theta\cos\phi\, d \theta \wedge d \phi
\end{align}

And I computed

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2+\cos\phi)^3\cos^3\theta\cos\phi d \theta d \phi$$

to be $0$. Sorry I have been asking lots of questions since yesterday I have a big diff geo final today and I wanna make sure I am computing the integrals of these forms correctly.

Comment: You never defined $M$

Comment: sorry, $M$ is the torus, the image of $F$, @Lorago

Comment: Yes, the answer is $0$. It is immediate to see by applying Stokes's Theorem and invoking symmetry. You should almost always think about what will be fastest on an exam.

Comment: @IvoTerek I do not quite see how $\omega=x^2\,dy\wedge dz$ is closed. $d\omega=2x\,dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\,.$ The integral of that over the solid torus is zero by $x\leftrightarrow -x$ symmetry combined with rotational symmetry around the $z$-axis by the angle $\theta\,.$

Comment: @Kurt You're right, I'm absolutely out of my mind. Let me even delete the wrong comment.